# Looking for a manga about a ghost girl and a boy who can see ghosts

Tags: story-identification, books, manga

I read this three or four years ago . . . the details are hazy. I looked this up but couldn't find it (since I read this online).

I remember:

- It's a manga! (surprise!)
- The main character is a boy
- He can see ghosts
- The ghost girl he meets was murdered and is trying to get revenge
- She takes him to get training (he's reluctant)
- The ghost girl has the power to make glass break [?] or at least imitate it
- There were five ghost trainers and a ghost master [?] at least 5
- Was a series

Is there any manga that fits this description?

**Edit:**

- He had a girlfriend but broke up with her at the start of the story
- White and black manga
- Somewhere between late high school age and late college age

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Are the protagonists high school students? Does the boy work as a detective?

Comment: @LogicDictates Black and white

Comment: @qazmlpok He was probably high school age, but I don't know if he was a student. He wasn't a detective though.

Comment: Just to check; I've never read it so I have no idea if any plot elements match, but can you confirm if this is "Tasogare Otome x Amnesia" / "Dusk Maiden of Amnesia" or not?

Comment: @qazmlpok Sorry, no. It isn't black and white, and I don't recognize any of the characters.

Comment: Sorry, by "It isn't black and white" do you mean that the story you're looking for is in full color, or that Tasogare Otome x Amnesia is in color? Tasogare Otome x Amnesia is definitely a black&white Japanese manga.

Comment: @qazmlpok The cover of the manga I'm looking for is black and white too, based on my memory. Apologies for the confusion.